# offsetTop always undefined in sticky navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, properties, navigationbar

I am making a navigation bar for my website, but the JavaScript property `offsetTop`, for some reason, doesn't work. I don't know if something is wrong with the navbar variable, or if it is the sticky variable, but something doesn't work.

This is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')

I have used `console.log` to see what values the variables really had and everything seemed to work, except the `sticky` variable which just said `undefined`.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementsByClassName("topnav");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    console.log("Hello")
  } else {
    console.log(navbar.offsetTop)
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #08acc2;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Hjem</a>
  <a href="https://scratch.mit.edu/" target="_blank">Scratch</a>
  <a href="contact/index.html">Kontakt</a>
  <a href="about/index.html">Om oss</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `getElementsByClassName()` returns `NodeList`, not an Element object. Therefore your call to get `offsetTop`, as well as `classlist.add()` and `classlist.remove()`, are failing.

To fix this you can use `querySelector()` instead, as this will return a single Element object - assuming the `.topnav` element is available in the DOM when your logic is invoked.

```
var navbar = document.querySelector(".topnav");
```

In addition, note that the logic itself can be simplified by using `classList.toggle()` and a boolean flag to indicate if the class should be added or removed:

```js
const navbar = document.querySelector(".topnav");
let navbarTop = navbar.offsetTop;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  navbar.classList.toggle('sticky', window.pageYOffset >= navbarTop);
});
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #08acc2;
  color: white;
}

#padding {
  height: 2000px;
}

.sticky { 
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Hjem</a>
  <a href="https://scratch.mit.edu/" target="_blank">Scratch</a>
  <a href="contact/index.html">Kontakt</a>
  <a href="about/index.html">Om oss</a>
</div>

<div id="padding"></div>
```